# displaying information in an ASP webpage

Tags: asp.net

what would be the best way to display information on a web page, I need something that can be dynamically created, so I get information and put that into a DataTable which needs to be dynamically displayed on a page. Each row of the table is a different set of info. The information is a combination of things; strings, decimal values and an image. Now I have a layout template on another page which I would like to keep intact on this page, I have had a look at an ASPxDataView but that seems to have it's own layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use an ASP.NET WebForms control to display data, and that you don't know which control to use?

Comment: if there is a control that would meet my requirements then yes

Comment: Way, way, way too broad

Comment: So I have a set of div's and that controls the layout for the info, so what I'm asking is, is there a control that I can "plug in" the already created layout into or not? A gridview is not sufficient for the way I would like to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a DataList which can keep the format of the controls by going into the item template, each item loaded will now have that item template. It displays all the types of info I need to display including images.